# Chat server with Twisted framework in python can't receive data from flash client

Tags: python, flash, twisted

I've develop a chat server using Twisted framework in Python.  It works fine with a Telnet client.  But when I use my flash client problem appear...

(the flash client work find with my old php chat server, I rewrote the server in python to gain performance)

The connexion is establish between the flash client and the twisted server: XMLSocket .onConnect return TRUE. So it's not a problem of permission with the policy file.

I'm not able to send any message from Flash clien with XMLSOCket function send(), nothing is receive on th server side.  I tried to end those message with '\n' or '\n\0' or '\0' without succes.

You have any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `LineOnlyReceiver.delimiter` is a pretty bad idea, since that changes the delivery for *all* instances of `LineOnlyReceiver` (unless they've changed it themselves on a subclass or on the instance).  If you ever happen to use any such code, it will probably break.

You should change `delimiter` by setting it on your `LineOnlyReceiver` subclass, since it's *your* subclass that has this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that the default delimiter for line, use by Twisted is '\r\n'.  It can be overwrite in a your children class with:

LineOnlyReceiver.delimiter = '\n'